# Alternative for Blob object for Firefox version < 13

Tags: javascript, firefox

Firefox 13+ Supports Blob, however for lower version what could be an alternative solution?

I have this code that creates a blob from bsae64 String:

```
    function base64ToBlob(base64) {
        var binary = $wnd.atob(base64);
        var len = binary.length;
        var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(len);
        var view = new Uint8Array(buffer);
        for ( var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                view[i] = binary.charCodeAt(i);
        }
        var blob = new Blob([ view ]);
        return blob;
    };
    var newBlob = base64ToBlob(b64);
    var URLObj = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    var source = URLObj.createObjectURL(newBlob);
    return source;
```

Running this on lower version Firefox throws `(TypeError): Blob is not a constructor`

Comment: Firefox has support for Blob from FF5. But prefix `moz` is needed to use it.

Comment: Like: var blob = new moz.Blob([view]);  ?